# What's bare minimum to enable networking on 20.10 / 20.04 (Base)

Tags: networking, 20.04, 20.10

I've been doing all kinds of toying and learning with Ubuntu Base, new subiquity installer, PXE, etc.
But one thing keeps haunting me - networking.

I can get my installations working, but installing `netplan.io` pulls just so so many required packages and needs even more on top to really work.

Is there any "legal" way without it? I did try with just `iproute2` and to do it manually, but I failed miserably, and I'd be most grateful for any ideas to get:

- networking to work
- dhcp or static, either is acceptable (less is better)
- resolving to work

Only test it has to really pass after configuration is for `apt-get update` to work. Then I can call it "fully functional".

Unfortunately, according to my experience so far, calling Ubuntu Base functional minimum from which you can install all other packages and build system as you wish is not really true if you don't have working networking.

As more info, my current bare setup (without networking) is:

- ubuntu-base-20.10-base-amd64.tar.gz
- linux-image-5.8.0-28-generic
- syslinux as bootloader
- removed man/docs
- removed apt cache
  (tried similar with 20.04.1)

This boots to sh, and I can start bash, and do some basics. apt is there but can't connect (obviously), so I'm stuck adding more packages.

I know I can throw a bunch of packages at it, and eventually it will work. But I'd like to have a bare minimum. Currently I have 370MB. Even with installing just netplan.io+dependencies, it goes to 470+ (~30% increase) and it still doesn't work. Going to `ubuntu-minimal` works, but that's 800MB+

I'm not exactly complete newb, but I've been struggling with all the netplan/iproute2 changes, and I'd really like to get it all working the "proper" way as envisioned in 20.10 & 20.04

Thanks!

Edit #1: As I just wrote in comment as answer (to comments that's now gone) I got it working by installing some extra packages during deployment :

```
apt-get install -y netplan.io dbus init iputils-ping isc-dhcp-client nano netbase ubuntu-advantage-tools sudo
```

Some I know are optional, but I need them till I'm done eliminating rest. I'm still trying to find which packages are really needed from this list (including their dependencies):

```
netplan.io init
```

Seems that installing `netplan.io`, `dbus` (recommended dependency of `netplan`) and `init` works, then I can create normal netplan .yaml etc, but that's a bit overkill just to get networking up, as I go from 370MB to 480MB just to get those.

Edit #2:
Current status: I can get it working with `dhclient` installed and some minimum of other tools. Complete list of installed packages (beyond Ubuntu Base rootfs):

```
chroot /mnt/root sh -c "apt-get install dbus init initramfs-tools iproute2 linux-image-5.8.0-28-generic sudo isc-dhcp-client --no-install-recommends"
```

So - no `netplan` required. But I still don't get it why I can't get it running with just `iproute` tools, because if I don't install `isc-dhcp-client` my manual `ip` commands don't work.

Does not work:

```
ip addr add 10.10.2.101/24 brd + dev enp0s10f0
ip link set enp0s10f0 up
ip route add default via 10.10.2.99
```

Does work:

```
dhclient -v -w
```

Edit #3: nevermind, `systemd-resolved` is now installed and it overwrote my `resolv.conf`. I can get it working now without DHCP. Need to try and remove DHCP package now and see if it still works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do not plan to submit bugs. But likewise official Ubuntu Base wiki page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base says `Ubuntu Base delivers a functional user-space environment, with full support for installation of additional software from the Ubuntu repositories, through the use of the apt-get command` and bit after lists requirements as `Ubuntu Base rootfs, Linux kernel for target device, boot-loader for target device`. Which in short isn't true. Later in text it says `Install Linux` (kernel?). And then `Install any additional required software using apt-get`. Without net?

Comment: I currently have it functional with following packages installed on top of what's listed in the Wiki (and it's requrements & procedure lists): `netplan.io dbus init iputils-ping isc-dhcp-client nano netbase ubuntu-advantage-tools sudo`. Few of those are there just to make sense of the system: sudo (as you login without root, so can't use apt without sudo), nano (just so I can check configs, it's optional), ping (to confirm networking works, optional), dhcp client (as I use dhcp, it's again optional). I'm in process of eliminating what's really needed from the rest, by pure trial and failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, to answer my own then... But please, if someone has even better way, do post your alternative!

Anyway, I had to do these preparation steps (for Ubuntu Base as such):

- prepare disk & partitions
- untar `ubuntu-base-20.10-base-amd64.tar.gz`
- open `chroot` and in it run following command
- **`apt-get install -y linux-image-5.8.0-28-generic initramfs-tools init dbus iproute2 sudo nano openssh-server --no-install-recommends`**
- while still in `chroot` add user and group membership with `useradd` and `addgroup`
- install and setup `syslinux` as bootloader
- copy `vmlinuz` and `initrd.img` to where `syslinux` expects them

Then to have correct network configuration after I exit chroot and reboot, add these:

**`(echo [Match]; echo Name=enp0s10f0; echo [Network]; echo Address=10.10.2.101/24; echo Gateway=10.10.2.99; echo DNS=8.8.8.8) > /mnt/root/etc/systemd/network/00-wired.network`**

And

**`systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service`**

Unmount, cleanup (`apt clean`), and `reboot`.

This process results in just under 400MB installation, and takes about 10 minutes (limited to network speed and my slow overburdened virtualization host).

After reboot I am greeted with login prompt as expected, can login with user and password I selected with `useradd`, can do `sudo`, and then can do `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` and all will go through without errors.

I did go step further to confirm no surprises would follow, and installed xserver, openbox, and chromium (from Debian repo), created another user, tried to `ssh` to the system, check and change settings with `ip`, you can then install dhcp-client afterwards and change the conf file to let DHCP take over, etc, and everything worked. I even squashed that whole partition next, and live-booted from it, everything working.

Now THAT can be called usable system. But those three lines in bold (apt install, 00-wired.network and enable systemd-networkd) are quite necessary, and not mentioned in any of the old guides and wikis (no wonder, those date from version 6 and similar).

To be exact, what's missing from those older guides is:

- you need to install: `init, dbus, iproute2 and sudo`
- those will pull other important (missing) hard dependencies such as: `systemd, systemd-sysv, udev`
- you need at least one working config in: `/etc/systemd/network/*.network`
- you need to enable service: `systemd-networkd.service`

Again, I know guides are (heavily) outdated, but unless you make workarounds, Ubuntu 20.10 isn't really Ubuntu 20.10 without `systemd`, and you can't really use `apt` without `sudo` (unless you disregard official ways of `root` being disabled, or similar). Only with these few elements added, can you really feel like you are in a ***minimal and functional*** (and, ahem, current) Ubuntu installation, with `systemd`, working network, and `apt` that can pull packages from official repos.

Hopefully someone notices and updates official wiki.